# Bootstrap select2 Auto Focus not working with jQuery 3.6.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

After migrating to jQuery 3.6.1 Bootstrap Select2 AutoFocus is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I've downgraded to jQuery 3.5.1 with this select2 started working.